# left is not a member of microsoft.visualbasic.strings

Tags: vb.net, string

While trying to get the left 2 characters out of a string I get the message:

'left' is nog a member of 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings'

Now until today I had allways thought that this would have to be the most simple things to solve. But...

Here's the code I am using:

```
If Strings.Left(ActivityCode, 2) = Selection Then
```

And that's all there is to it! What is wrong here?

Peter

Comment: Isn't it just `Left(....)`?

Comment: Let go of your Visual Basic past.  Embrace the now.  `ActivityCode.Substring(0, 2)`

Comment: A part from the advices above the Strings.Left should work as well

Comment: Thanks LarsTech, this works! I'm not sure if I will ever be able to let go of my VB past, but I'm allways prepared to adopt new and better, if available. In this case your suggestion seems to be just that! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use .NET string methods instead?

```
Dim leftTwo = If(activityCode.Length <= 2, activityCode, activityCode.Remove(2))
If leftTwo = Selection Then
    ' ... '
End If
```

For what it's worth, you could also create an extension if you're missing this method:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module StringExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function Left(Str As String, takeLeft As Int32) As String
        If takeLeft < 0 Then Throw New ArgumentException("takeLeft must be greater than or equal 0", "takeLeft")
        If Str Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        If Str.Length <= takeLeft Then Return Str
        Return Str.Remove(takeLeft)
    End Function
End Module
```

Now you can use it in this way:

```
If activityCode.Left(2) = Selection Then
    ' ...' 
End If
```

Comment: Good job @TimSchmelter! The .Net string methods are the solution. ANd to answer your initial question: Why I don't use this? because I used the "old" syntax and that worked until now. No further arguments. Your extension method seems a bit overkill... But thanks for the suggestion anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

Use it this way:

```
Dim TestString As String = "Hello World!" 
' Returns "Hello". 
Dim subString As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(TestString, 5)
```

But you should really use .NET methods like `.SubString()`

Comment: It wasn't me but if I had to guess. It's because you said to use LEFT() and then said you should "really" do something else. Irony.

Comment: I was only suggesting, as using .NET modern methods is more advisable, I guess.

Comment: @JhonAlx: your first suggestion is really wrong! That is just a rephrase of my initial code and wont work either. The second part contains the suggestion that was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Investigating a bit deeper, based on the suggestions given (thank you all!!!) I think the key to the solution lies in the fact that my original codesnippet is part of a Windows 8.1 Store App project. I was not aware of the fact that the Microsoft.VisualBasic library is appearently not available in that kind of project. So I HAVE to switch to the .NET variants of the syntax.

So in spite of the suggestions telling that it HAS to work, it simply seems impossible.

Am I right?